# How to get rows from one or another joined table and then further to more joined tables depending on which first two tables were joined

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have three tables (a, b, c) and two (b and c) need to be joined to get detail data from the first table a. But the problem is that I need to do this in one query.

If I join both tables in the same query than no records are found as detail data is either in b or c, but never in both.

To further complicate things, I need to further join other tables (b2, c2) based on with the record found is from b or c.

I am using MS SQL.

The query I have now is:

```
select a.*, b.name1, c.name1, b2.url, c2.url
  left join b on a.aID = b.aID
  left join c on a.aID = c.aID
  inner join b2 on b.bID = b2.bID
  inner join c2 on c.cID = c2.cID
where a.date > '9/1/2016'
```

I searched for a few days, but no one seems to need to go after the fourth and fifth tables in the query and so couldn't find any similar answer

Is there any way to do this? Performance is not an issue as the number of records will be less than 1,000 after executing a where clause that will always limit the records from table a.

Comment: `JOIN` is just short-hand for `INNER JOIN`, so it's important to realize that you're just doing 4 inner joins. An `INNER JOIN` only grabs records where a match is found. If you want to select *all values* from one table, and then find additional information *where applicable*, you should look into doing a `LEFT JOIN` instead.

Comment: I updated the code to use LEFT JOIN, but the query still doesn't work to pull the data from the b2 and c2 tables. No records are found at all actually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A series of left joins with inner joins as subqueries should do the trick.  The subqueries pull the b/b2 and c/c2 data together for reference in the left joins with a:

```
select a.*, b.name1, c.name1, b2join.url, c2join.url
FROM a
LEFT JOIN b
    on a.aID = b.aID
LEFT JOIN c
    on a.aID = c.aID
LEFT JOIN 
        (SELECT b.aID, b.bID, b2.url
            FROM b
        INNER JOIN b2
            on b.bID = b2.bID) as b2join
    on b2join.aID = a.aID
LEFT JOIN 
        (SELECT c.aID, c.cID, c2.url
            FROM c
        INNER JOIN c2
            on c.cID = c2.cID) as c2join
    on c2join.aID = a.aID
```

Comment: the key on the b2 and c2 tables needs to come from the b and c tables so the left joins using a.aID on the b2 and c2 tables wont help in this scenario

Comment: @JunaidAli I realized that right after I posted the answer :-)  Updated the answer to account for this now.

Comment: This worked with slight change. But I used b2join.bID = b.bID (a different column to go after the b2 table data). This instead of "b2join.aID = a.aID". Similar way I got to the c2 table data.

Answer (score 0):

I think a Left Join will do it, at least for the first part:

```
select a.*, b.name1, c.name1
  left join b on a.aID = b.aID
  left join c on a.aID = c.aID
where a.date > '9/1/2016'
```

You will get c.name1 null when data is in b table, and b.name1 will be null when data is in c table.

For the other two joins and not sure but left join could also work.

Comment: the left join works for the tables b and c. Left joins don't work on the b2 and c2 tables though in this case

Answer (score 0):

I think, it is more simple and brief way to get the same result:

```
select a.*, b.name1, c.name1, b2join.url, c2join.url
FROM a
LEFT JOIN b on a.aID = b.aID
LEFT JOIN c on a.aID = c.aID
LEFT JOIN b as b2join on b2join.bID = b.bID
LEFT JOIN a as c2join on c2join.cID = c.cID
```